# Bootstrap in sharepoint web part

Tags: sharepoint, twitter-bootstrap-3, sharepoint-2010

Does anyone know of a good way to use Bootstrap styles for a SharePoint web part? I don't want to restyle the entire SharePoint site with bootstrap styles. I just want to be able to use bootstrap elements like buttons and forms and modals within a SharePoint web part without interfering with the regular SharePoint styles on the rest of the site. So with that in mind looking at the example below should give a good picture of what I want. Basically I want to reset the styles and then apply bootstrap styling within the div with ID BootstrapContent but everything outside of that div should be unaffected and just use the normal SharePoint styles. Thanks for the help.

```
<html>
 <body>
  STANDARD SHAREPOINT STYLES
  <div id='BootstrapContent'>
    HTML CONTENT WITH BOOTSTRAP STYLES
  </div>
  STANDARD SHAREPOINT STYLES
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use bootstrap class only in your webpart , that doesn't effect other part of the site .. reference bootstrap files in master page ..

Comment: No I can't do that because including bootstrap in the masterpage creates conflicts between default SharePoint css and the bootstrap css. I might have a solution but I'm not done testing yet. I added a wrapper to the main bootstrap less files and then recompiled the css effectively letting me scope the bootstrap styles to a container div. If everything works out I will post details to my solution here.

Comment: you can try this : http://www.topsharepoint.com/shareboot-responsive-sharepoint-2013-theme

Comment: No I can't, I am on sharepoint 2010 and we don't want the entire masterpage to be changed. I just want to be able to use bootstrap within a web part we are working on. I have found a solution and almost have the bugs worked out and I will post here with the final solution.

Comment: you can custom a scope/namespace bootstrap suing SASS or LESS

Answer (score 1):

There's no good way to isolate one part of your html without using iFrames.  If you went that way you could put your html into a doc lib, then call it from an iframe.  That html file would reference bootstrap and only affect the iframe.  You can use the Page Viewer web part to create the iframe for you.

Another option which isn't quite what you are asking, is you could get a cut down (customized) version of bootstrap [customized](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/).  If you only need the grid system for example, only get that option.  You might be able to exclude a lot of the generic things that interfere with SP.  However, you'd likely lose things you want.